# Drop multiple tables execSQL

Tags: android, sqlite

Ok maybe i just do not understand this but, when i try to drop multiple tables like

```
static final String DROP_TABLES = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ?,?,?,?";
```

and try to execute this via:

```
db.execSQL(DROP_TABLES, new Object[]{"table1", "table2", "table3", "table4"})
```

it won´t work

also i get an error message for

```
  private static final String DROP_TABLES = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ?,?,?,?";
```

> <'database name> or <'defined table name> expected, got '?'

i really don´t know whats going wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `?` only for binding literal values. You cannot use it for binding identifiers such as table names.

Additionally, you can only drop one table at a time.

So:

1. Use the table name in the SQL string itself.
2. `DROP TABLE` only one table at a time, one SQL statement per `execSQL()` call.

Comment: but why then javadoc says its good to use for drop table if exists with bindArgs? I thought i can use something like "drop table if exists arg1, arg2, arg3" ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object[]) maybe i just got it wrong?

Comment: `execSQL()` is a generic method and accepts bind args but that's only useful for statements where the SQL syntax permits it. The doc says nothing about using args with `DROP TABLE`.